# Haskell take first Char of list and append at end of that list

Tags: haskell, tail

Given:

```
mangle :: String -> String
```

and I want to do something like:

```
mangle xs = head xs -- works if you change typesig to [a] -> a
```

but:

```
mangle xs = tail xs ++ head xs -- won't work at all!
```

Would like to append the first Char of a list at the end of that list, cutting that first Char.

Comment: `[head xs]` will convert the char into a string, so you can append it, but your function is not safe.

Comment: Never use `head,tail`, use pattern matching instead.

Comment: @Michael Kohl: thanks! That is really straightforward. Should have figured that out.

Comment: @Chi: why not use head or tail? One could make an 'error' clause. Sorry to say but it seemed to me that pattern matching made it more complicated than necessary. And note: I am a beginner starting to grasp the power (and complexity) or Haskell ;-)

Comment: @Madderote `head,tail` are partial operations: they will crash your program when they are fed with an empty list. Pattern matching is also often simpler to write e.g. compare your code with `mangle (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]`. Further, enabling warnings will make GHC report the missing cases in pattern matching. Code like `if (x.canFoo()) { x.foo() }` is common in say Java, where `x.foo()` will crash if we forget the previous check. In Haskell, similar code is an antipattern, since (exhaustive) pattern matching is a safer, and often simpler alternative.

Answer (score 6):

A very straight-forward solution could look like this:

```
mangle :: String -> String
mangle [] = []
mangle (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```